# How can I view/log session data on my express server?

Tags: javascript, express, debugging, redis, express-session

I'm using express and express-session for sessions.  I used the following code:

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  console.log("DEBUG: req.session", req.session);
  next();
});
```

but, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

I have a very simple app and I just wanted to verify what data is being stored by my express-session.

I am using Redis, but I don't think the session store should matter, i.e. it should be the same value even if I use the default store.

Answer (score 0):

Your code LGTM, just make sure that your middleware is registered after the `express-session` middleware

```js
app.use(
  session({
    // config...
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('DEBUG: req.session', req.session);
  next();
});
```